How can I use conditional formatting to turn my cells 1 color when they match the same cell in another tab, and another color when they don't match?
I have two tabs and I want to set conditional formatting in the first tab based on the exact same cells in the second tab.
Example: if (Tab1!N3=Tab2!N3) turn the cell green. If (Tab1!N3<>Tab2!N3) turn the cell red.
I've tried using MATCH and INDIRECT functions as I've found many such solutions through googling this issue. But they all only change the cell if it does match, and no change if it doesn't match. And the closest formula I found [=match(C2,indirect("data list!A2:A"),0)] checks my cell against the entire column, and I want to check against only 1 cell.

Within Conditional Formatting Rules try:
Apply to range: A:Z
Custom Formula: =A1=indirect("Tab2!"&address(row(),column()))
If you wish to skip blank cells as a match,then use: =len(A1)*(A1=indirect("Tab2!"&address(row(),column())))

This worked for cells that match! Thank you!!
Just to note if anyone in my situation: I added the same forumla to the same range and replaced "A1=indirect" with "A1<>indirect" and selected a different color to apply for cells that do not match.
